# how to add Blue facebook button to canvas app

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a Facebook iframe canvas app using PHP.

I need to my button to look like a Facebook button.

How to do this ... can any one share the CSS to do that?

Comment: Why don't you use the actual Facebook image?

Comment: i really don't know anything please suggest me , thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the STYLESHEET:**

```
<style>
.uiButton,.uiButtonSuppressed:active,.uiButtonSuppressed:focus,.uiButtonSuppressed:hover{background:#eee url('images/B4K_BWwP7P5.png') repeat 0 0;border:1px solid #999;border-bottom-color:#888;box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);cursor:pointer;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;line-height:normal !important;padding:2px 6px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap}
.uiButton + .uiButton{margin-left:4px}
.uiButton:hover{text-decoration:none}
.uiButton:active,.uiButtonDepressed{background:#ddd;border-bottom-color:#999;box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)}
.uiButton .img{margin-top:2px;vertical-align:top}
.uiButtonLarge .img{margin-top:4px}
.uiButton .customimg{margin-top:0}
.uiButton .uiButtonText,.uiButton input{background:none;border:0;color:#333;cursor:pointer;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;font-family:'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;margin:0;outline:none;padding:1px 0 2px;white-space:nowrap}
.uiButtonSpecial{background-color:#69a74e;background-position:0 -96px;border-color:#3b6e22 #3b6e22 #2c5115}
.uiButtonSpecial:active{background:#609946;border-bottom-color:#3b6e22}
.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled,.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled:active,.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled:focus,.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled:hover{background:#b4d3a7;border-color:#9db791}
.uiButtonConfirm{background-color:#5b74a8;background-position:0 -48px;border-color:#29447e #29447e #1a356e}
.uiButtonConfirm:active{background:#4f6aa3;border-bottom-color:#29447e}
.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled,.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled:active,.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled:focus,.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled:hover{background:#adbad4;border-color:#94a2bf}
.uiButtonSpecial .uiButtonText,.uiButtonSpecial input,.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled .uiButtonText,.uiButtonSpecial.uiButtonDisabled input,.uiButtonConfirm .uiButtonText,.uiButtonConfirm input,.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled .uiButtonText,.uiButtonConfirm.uiButtonDisabled input{color:#fff}
.uiButtonDisabled,.uiButtonDisabled:active,.uiButtonDisabled:focus,.uiButtonDisabled:hover{background:#f2f2f2;border-color:#c8c8c8;box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none}
.uiButtonDisabled .img{opacity:.5}
.uiButtonDisabled .uiButtonText,.uiButtonDisabled input{color:#b8b8b8}
.uiButtonDepressed,.uiButtonDepressed .uiButtonText,.uiButtonDepressed input,.uiButtonDisabled,.uiButtonDisabled .uiButtonText,.uiButtonDisabled input{cursor:default}
.uiButtonLarge,.uiButtonLarge .uiButtonText,.uiButtonLarge input{font-size:13px}
.uiButtonSuppressed{background:none;border-color:transparent;box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none}
.uiButtonNoText .img{margin-left:-1px;margin-right:-1px}

</style>
```

**THE DOM CODE**

**SILVER BUTTON**

```
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonText uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonText uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonText" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonText" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<br><br>
```

**BLUE BUTTON**

```
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonConfirm uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonConfirm" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<br><br>
```

**GREEN BUTTON**

```
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonSpecial uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonSpecial uiButtonDisabled" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge uiButtonSpecial" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<label class="uiButton uiButtonText" for="u217078_2323"><input value="Sign Up" onclick="" type="submit" id="u217078_2323"></label>
<br><br>
```

**AND THE IMAGE**
Put the image in the `images` folder,

[image]

**The RESULT**

[image]
**And you are done :) this is my script that i use on my pages**

Comment: that not for page its for application , can i use this in my application

Comment: Its the raw css and html code that you can use on your app.. this code is like a normal css template available out on the sites. this is not dependent of facebook.

Comment: If you find this answer to be useful, then dont forget to mark it as correct by clicking the small tickmark on the left of this answer.